# Input returning NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nan

Hi I'm new to js and trying to create a simple calculation but the result is always NaN
here is my code:

```js
const calculator = document.getElementById("calculator");

var firstNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("firstNumber").value;

var secondNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("secondNumber").value;

calculator.addEventListener('submit', function() {

  event.preventDefault();

  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;

  alert(result);

})
```

```html
<form id="calculator">

  <input type="number" class="firstNumber" min="1" value="1">

  <input type="number" class="secondNumber" min="1" value="1">

  <input type='submit'>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Instead, try indexing them:

```
const calculator = document.getElementById("calculator");
var firstNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("firstNumber")[0].value;
var secondNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("secondNumber")[0].value;
calculator.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    alert(result);
});
```

Another ~issue~ is that you do not convert to a number and the `input` returns a string. This is a stylistic choice, since javascript will implicitly cast to a number, but try using `parseFloat`:

```
var firstNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("firstNumber")[0].value);
var secondNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("secondNumber")[0].value);
```

---

```js
   const calculator = document.getElementById("calculator");

calculator.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var firstNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("firstNumber")[0].value;
  var secondNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("secondNumber")[0].value;
  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  alert(result);
})
```

```html
<form id="calculator">
<input type="number" class="firstNumber" min="1" value="1">
<input type="number" class="secondNumber" min="1" value="1">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had two problems in your code:

1) You need to fetch the values inside the submit function, otherwise they are fetched on initial page load and won't get updated with what the user actually enters.

2) (This was the direct cause of your `NaN` result): `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) - that is, a structure representing a *collection* of potentially many elements. (This makes sense because you can have multiple elements of a given class.) So it doesn't really make sense for this to have a `value` property - and it doesn't. I've fixed below by simply using a `[0]` index accessor to get the first such element - but you may wish to replace the class by an `id` and use `document.getElementById` instead (which does return a single element).

See working version below, with the above points fixed.

```js
const calculator = document.getElementById("calculator");

calculator.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var firstNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("firstNumber")[0].value;
  var secondNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("secondNumber")[0].value;
  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  alert(result);
})
```

```html
<form id="calculator">
<input type="number" class="firstNumber" min="1" value="1">
<input type="number" class="secondNumber" min="1" value="1">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Both values are strings so you'll have to covert them to number s in the function that handles them. Try  `const result = Number(firstNumber) * Number(secondNumber);`